# Frank setup giving error,

Tags: ios, ruby, terminal, rubygems, cucumber

I am trying to setup frank-cucumber using [this](http://blog.thepete.net/blog/2012/06/24/writing-your-first-frank-test/) set of instructions.

After doing this:

`sudo gem install frank-cucumber`

I get an error saying this:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:230:in activate: can't activate i18n (= 0.6.1, runtime) for ["activesupport-3.2.13", "xcodeproj-0.5.5", "frank-cucumber-1.1.8"], already activated i18n-0.6.4 for ["frank-cucumber-1.1.8"] (Gem::LoadError)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with your gem dependencies; activesupport 3.2.13 requires i18n version 0.6.1, but frank has already loaded i18n version 0.6.4.  The `gem` command probably installed i18n-0.6.4 automatically when you installed frank (it saw that frank needed any version of i18n, so it installed the latest).

The first quick fix I'd try is `sudo gem uninstall i18n --version 0.6.4`.  That should leave you with just version 0.6.1 installed, and both frank and activesupport should be happy.  But if you are going to continue adding more gems, potentially creating more dependency conflicts, you should look into integrating [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) into your process.